# Adding a table using javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Beginner here, but I have spent a long time trawling other questions to try to debug this. My issue is as follows:

I take two arrays, 'left' and 'right', calculate the ratios between them (with a function that I already have working) outputting a 3x11 array with the ratios.

What I'm trying to produce in the end is a table with 4 rows and 12 columns. The [0] row will list 'right', the [0] column will list left, and the rest of the table will then host the corresponding ratios.

It should then replace the relevant div within the html.

Maybe it's something obvious and I'm just totally missing it, or it's just a hole in my knowledge. Either way, I've spent most of the day on it!

```
<!-- html -->

<body>
<input type="input" value="Enter a value"></input>
<div id="results_table">
Ratios:
    <div id="result">ratios listed here</div>
    <div id="result1">tables here</div>
</div>
</body>


//Javascript\\

$("input").change(function () {
    var left = new Array(3);                         
    var right = new Array(11);
    left = [30, 40, 50];
    right = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]; 
    result = fullCalc(left, right);                       //this calculates the ratios
    $("#result").append(result);
    var ratios = result;    
    resultstable = tableCreate(left,right,ratios);
    $("#result1").append(resultsTable);
});


function tableCreate(a, b, c) {

newTable = document.getElementById("result1");
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
tbl.style.width = '100%';
tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
tbl.setAttribute('id', "results_tbl");

for (var i = 0; i < a.length + 1; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute('id', "tablerow" + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length + 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        if (i >= 1 && j === 0) {
            var frontText = document.createTextNode(a[i-1]);
            td.append(leftText);
            td.setAttribute('id', "leftTable");
        } else if (i === 0 && j >= 1) {
            var rearText = document.createTextNode(b[j-1]);
            td.append(rearText);
            td.setAttribute('id', "rightTable");
        } else {
            var ratioText = document.createTextNode(c[i-1][j-1]);
            td.appendChild(ratioText);
            td.setAttribute('id', "ratioTable");
        }

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
}
tbl.appendChild(tbdy);

}
```

The problem is that no table appears, and I'm unsure if one is even being created. Any ideas?

Comment: `var left = new Array(3);` fine, old syntax but valid. `left = [30, 40, 50];` now you overrided the array you allocated before, just use the second line. also, you never declared `result`.

Comment: you never returned a table from tableCreate

Comment: Why bother with jQuery at all if you're going to add a table piece by piece using vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks gdoron. I thought you had to declare an empty array before 'filling' it with values, but evidently not.

I've added a return in tableCreate but hasn't seemed to work yet...

Blazemonger, I know it's probably not the most efficient way to go, but I'm trying to learn jQuery too and implement it where I can along the way at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out!

The problem was that I was forcing the for loop that fills the table to look for a value that wasn't there.ie. when j = 0 and i = 0, the 'else if' was trying to find values at c[-1][-1] which obviously doesn't exist. I simply added another 'else if' to accommodate the [0][0] position on the table:

```
else if ( i === 0 && j ===0){
    var variableText = document.createTextNode("variables");
    td.appendChild(variableText);
    td.setAttribute('id', "variableTable");
}
```

Almost a pity it was just a programming error. Thanks to all for the help with improving my code though.

Answer (score 3):

So close! You have to append your `table` somewhere:

```
tbl.appendChild(tbdy); //it has a tbody, but where is the table
//APPEND TO AN ELEMENT
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not sure I understand this answer. I have a line of code that says exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a combination of typeJV's answer and Kevin B's comment.

You *do* have a line of code that appends the result of tableCreate, but you *don't* return a value from that function, so no append occurs.

You also appear to have some typos in your script, including:

```
// create a (global) variable name with no capital letters
resultstable = tableCreate(left,right,ratios);
// refer to the variable name with a capital 'T' - that's a different variable
$("#result1").append(resultsTable);

// do you mean to make this a global variable?
newTable = document.getElementById("result1");
```

gdoron is also correct that these lines are redundant:

```
var left = new Array(3);   // allocate a new array
var right = new Array(11);
left = [30, 40, 50];       // throw away that array and create a brand new one
right = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]; // same here
result = fullCalc(left, right);  // another undeclared var - this becomes global
```

Comment: Thank you. How would making newTable a global variable change things?

Comment: It wouldn't change the behavior of this code directly, but creating global variables is generally a Bad Thing, certainly if you do it by accident.  You don't want your code to over-write a value created in some other code on accident, or vice-versa.  Usually when writing JS we try to stay out of the global namespace.